# How to get last two directories from a path using regexp?

Tags: java, regex

I have a path `C:\input\rsgc\statements_and_inserts\Australia\` and I want to get the last two directories using regular expression in java. It can be done in few steps. I do not know how many directories are in the path but I always want the last two.

Can this be done in reg exp or I need to use programming language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this regex you get two groups where the first is the second-last directory and the second the last directory:

```
\\([^\\]+)\\([^\\]+)\\$
```

You can test it [here](http://regex101.com/r/dD9bB4/1).

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use the following regex:

```
(.+?)((?:(?:(?!\/).)+?\/){0,2}(?:(?!\/).)+?$)
```

The second capturing group will give the required result.
This presents the advantage that one can get the other part of the path (the first capturing group ) as well if needed.
Another advantage is that this also matches directories even if it contains fewer than 2 sub-directories.
For Windows, change forward slashes to backward slashes and appropriate changes to include drive letters.
You can test this here : https://regex101.com/r/WiXZkP/1

Answer (score 0):

```
path = "C:\input\rsgc\statements_and_inserts\Australia\";
path = path.substring(0,path.length()-1);
String filename = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("\") + 1);
String subPath = path.replace("\" + filename, "");
String lastTwoDir = path.substring(subPath.lastIndexOf("\") + 1);
```

Comment: path = path.substring(0,path.length()-1); remove "\" after "Australia" now path is "C:\input\rsgc\statements_and_inserts\Australia\"

Comment: now "lastTwoDir"  give result "statements_and_inserts\Australia"